# Javascript replace() to remove single quote produces weird result

Tags: javascript

With this code

`"test\536".replace(/'/g, "")`

I would expect there is no different to the original string, because there is no single quote. But I get this instead

`"test+6"`

When I run this on a string with single quote, it works as expected

```
"test'536".replace(/'/g, "")
"test536"
```

Comment: You need to double-escape that slash: `test\\536`. It's not the replace that's doing it, you're inserting an escape sequence.

Comment: @MikeC, would you please write it as an answer? Those rep points belong to you.

Comment: @Shomz Because this is just a typo error and should be closed as such. I don't like scraping rep off of dying questions ;)

Comment: I understand, but someone else will scrape off **your** rep, I'd much rather if you took it :)

Comment: @Shomz Fair point. I'll keep that in mind :)

Comment: Hang on, `test\536` is exactly what I retrieved from the database. So how can I get rid of the single quote, without causing this weird escape behaviour?

Comment: As has been mentioned by several people, you'll have to escape the backslash. How you do that depends on the language you use to generate the JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in your string, in JavaScript strings `\` is used to escape the following character. so if you want to prevent this behavior you should escape it using another slash, it will be `\\`:

```
"test\\536".replace(/'/g, "")
```

```js
console.log("test\\536".replace(/'/g, ""));
console.log("test'536".replace(/'/g, ""));
```

Hope this helps.